# Android Exoplayer display ms in current position text

Tags: android, exoplayer

Would it be possible to format the field that displays the current video position e.g. 00:01, 00:02, 00:003... etc to something more precise, to ms? and display like 0.100 (100ms),0.200(200ms) and so on?

Comment: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html

Comment: this shows some methods that use milliseconds to calculate, try looking through that

Comment: yes, you can get the current position at any given time, but thats different from updating constantly the current position display of the controller